# Does s:url (in Struts2) not do url-rewriting like c:url does in case cookies are disabled?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

The **Servlet API** resorts to URL rewriting if cookies are disabled.. and every URL that we provide in our JSPs must be inside `c:url` for this to be in effect. But, in **Struts 2**, there is an equivalent tag `s:url`, but its documentation says nothing about automatically adding url-rewriting information (if required) to the url. Is its behaviour similar in this regards to `c:url`, or do we have some other means to achieve the same effect in Struts 2 ?

I am using Struts 2.1 url tag reference from [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/url.html)

**Clarification** : In case that the user disables cookies, the other option is to append the `jseesionid` to each url that is there on the page. `c:url` handles that for us. My question is that whether `s:url` does the same thing for us. I was worried as its not mentioned in the documentation link I provided  above.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement? What is it exactly you need the tag to do, possibly with an example.

Comment: I have added some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Yes struts2 will do this too.  Simply disable cookies and you should see a session id is put into the url (when using s:a tags, I have not tested url tags). I'm glad you added clarification because this is url writing.  Url rewriting is done as urls come into the server, where they are then rewritten by certain rules generally so they get directed to the right place within the server(which is not at all what is happening here).

**Edit**: Thanks to Daud, the correct term is url-rewiting. This is because session management is handled by the container level, although struts2 can manipulate what the session contains, it is the container which provides the session via a "session manager" object and determines how persistence is best managed (including generating the jSession Id).

For details on this for **glassfish**: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaha.html#beahf

For details on this for **tomcat**: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence

For other containers simply google: Container_Name + "session manager"

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but I think that url rewriting is the standard term used for placing a session id in the URL in EE parlance. A google search with 'java sessions url rewriting' came up with exactly the sense in which I was using url-rewriting)